# Efficient algorithm that decides if an edge belongs to some cycle

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to struct an efficient algorithm gets undirected graph, and edge e(u,v), and decides if the edge belongs to some cycle in the graph ,but not all of the cycles!
My approach is to take out the edge (u,v) from the graph, and run BFS to see if v is still reachable from u. If yes then the original graph has a cycle containing e, otherwise there isn't.
But i'm not so sure how to tweak the algorithm that it will decide if the edge doesn't belong to all the cycles of the graph.

Comment: Maybe something counter intuitive: search for a cycle that doesn't have particular edge : if there's at least one then not all cycles have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An undirected graph can contain an edge which belongs to all of its cycles graph only if this graph has a single cycle.

Let's look at an example. Edge (2,3) belongs to two cycles, but you always can find a third cycle to which such an edge doesn't belong.

[image: Graph with cycles 125, 12345]

After you have checked that the edge belongs to some cycle, you can check if this is the only cycle in the graph by removing this edge and checking if the reduced graph has any cycles at all. Thanks to @nomanpouigt for pointing that out.

Comment: Oh so if the graph has more then 1 cycle then a specific edge can't  belong to all of them? So the algorithm i wrote is sufficien to use?

Comment: @123josh123 yes

Comment: @Yola are you sure OP algorithm going to work? Wouldn't just removing the edge and checking if there are no more cycles in the graph going to tell us if a given edge is present in all the cycles or not?

Comment: @nomanpouigt if graph contains more than one cycle then OP algortihm going to work. I think it can be combined with your approach to test if it is the only cycle.